# EPiServer 7.5 CMS won't install because of missing MVC 4, but I already have Visual Studio 2017 installed

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, installation, content-management-system, episerver

I'm trying to install EPiServer 7.5 CMS Deployment Center from world.episerver.com.

However, every time I try to install it I get an error saying "The setup did not find ASP.NET MVC 4 which is required by this product."

I have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise installed on the computer, but doesn't MVC already ship with VS? I can't seem to find anywhere to download MVC 4.

Comment: Did you enable the MVC 4 Package in the installer window as Eric's suggestion? Would you please share the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options

- Download the latest version of MVC at https://www.asp.net/downloads
- Standalone installer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/mvc4
- Ensure MVC 4 is installed using the Visual Studio Installer

[image]